# Pull repo, create branch and then make a pull request

Tags: git, github

I've been given a task which involves me pulling some code from a remote git repo and creating a branch. My git knowledge is limited to updating my own GitHub so I'm really not sure I've got the following steps right:

Firstly to pull from the repo I need to get the remote URL from the GitHub page, change directory to where I want to write my code and then do:

```
Git clone remote_url
```

Then to create a branch I think I need to do:

```
git checkout -b my_branch
```

So far I'm hoping this is correct. Do I need to change directory locally to the new branch at all before writing code or has the checkout taken care of that ?

When I'm finished coding the instructions are to create a pull request. The only place I can see to make a pull request is on the GitHub page for the remote repo. I'm assuming I need to do push the code back up first using:

```
Git add *
git commit -m 
git push
```

before that ?

Comment: *Do I need to change directory locally to the new branch* you misunderstand. A branch is not a separate directory. Its a version of the project altogether so to say

Comment: Right ok , thanks for the clarification on that.

Comment: Can you push to the repository you cloned? If so, push your branch, and github will suggest you to create a pull request. If notn then you should have forked the repo first, clone your own fork, pushed to your own fork, and then make a PR.

Comment: `git add .` not a good practice...`git commit -m "some message"` and 
`git push origin my_branch` should be the complete command

Comment: @nullpointer thanks. What's better practice for git add? Add each file explicitly ? The git push origin my_branch was the info I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git add .` is not a good practice, you might want to practice

```
git add <path and name of the file to be added>
```

`git commit -m "some message"` adds a message for the commits you are making presently.

`git push origin my_branch` should be the complete command to push changes to your checked out branch.

Once this is done successfully you can see an option to create a Pull Request on the repository on GitHub.